# ASP.NET Razor Edit Data Page

Tags: asp.net, html, ado.net, razor

i have some problem here with Edit Data Using ASP.NET Razor in WebMatrix 
i write this code for edit a data using the Update command but unfortunately it doesnt work :s :s

Razor code :

```
    @{
      {
            var userId = Request["UserId"];
    var db = Database.Open("intranet");
    var query = "UPDATE Personne SET Demande = @0 WHERE UserId LIKE '%@1%'";
    db.Execute(query,"refuser", userId);
 }
    }
```

the html code :

```
<form action="responsable.cshtml" method="post">
<input type="hidden" name="UserId" value="saadwafqui" />
<input type="submit" value="Oui" />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try like this:

```
var query = "UPDATE Personne SET Demande = @0 WHERE UserId LIKE '%'+@1+'%'";
```

Comment: yes Darin when i try the commande like that it gives me this page : http://data.imagup.com/11/1144944948.PNG
and when i try this : 
var query = "UPDATE Personne SET Demande = @0 WHERE UserId LIKE '%@1%'";
at less the ereur msg didn't rise again but it steel des'nt update tha commande in the data :s

Comment: Maybe it's because you don't have matching records in your database that meet the criteria?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following code:

```
@{
  if (IsPost){
    var userId = Request["UserId"];
    var db = Database.Open("intranet");
    var query = "UPDATE Personne SET Demande = @0 WHERE UserId LIKE '%" + userId + "%'";
    db.Execute(query,"refuser" );
  }


}
```

the html code :

```
<form action="responsable.cshtml" method="post">
<input type="hidden" name="UserId" value="saadwafqui" />
<input type="submit" value="Oui" />
```